# JavaScript onClick function constructed in PHP does not work in the ajax response back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am sending an ajax request to load some information constructed in a div from PHP. There is an onClick function there. Ajax responds well, but the JavaScript function does not work in the HTML client.

This is the response from ajax written in PHP:

```
    $iscId = $row['instructorSemesterCourseId'];
    $year = $row['year'];
    $startDate = $row['startDate'];
    $endDate = $row['endDate'];
    $courseCredit = $row['courseCredit'];
    $pinned = $row['pinned'];
    $semesterName = $row['semesterName'];

    $date1 = date('F j, Y', strtotime($startDate)); 
    $date2 = date('F j, Y', strtotime($endDate));

    $div .= "<div id='SCid".$iscId."' class='schoolClass'>
                  <div class='schoolClassLeft'>
                    <div class='schoolCourseTitle'  onClick='classSessionEnter('SCid".$iscId."'); style='width:100%'>".$semesterName." ".$year." | ".$date1." &ndash; ".$date2."</div>
                  </div>
                </div>";
    echo('$div');
```

The function written in JavaScript and jQuery is:

```
function classSessionEnter(elm) {
    alert('elm');
    $('#' + elm).css({"background": "#E7F9CE"});
    $('#' + elm).css({"position": "absolute"});
    $('#' + elm).css({"top": "0px"});
    $('#' + elm).css({"color": "#006600"});
}
```

The alert does not work - it does not get into the function at all. Why?

Comment: You should scape some single quotes for this to work. Try: onClick='classSessionEnter(\'SCid".$iscId."\');'

Comment: Yes it is in the global space. It seems the error is coming from the function's variable. When I remove the variable from the function, it will enter into the function.

Comment: Thanks Michael for editing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$div .= "<div id='SCid".$iscId."' class='schoolClass'>
    <div class='schoolClassLeft'>
        <div class='schoolCourseTitle' onClick=\"classSessionEnter('SCid".$iscId."')\"; style='width:100%'>".$semesterName." ".$year." | ".$date1." &ndash; ".$date2."</div>
     </div>
</div>";
```

You should esacpe the quotes first 「onClick=\"」

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great right now. Couple of hours struggling with this.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
$div .= "<div id='SCid".$iscId."' class='schoolClass'>
              <div class='schoolClassLeft'>
                <div class='schoolCourseTitle'  onClick='classSessionEnter('SCid".$iscId."'); style='width:100%'>".$semesterName." ".$year." | ".$date1." &ndash; ".$date2."</div>
              </div>
            </div>";
echo('$div');
```

with this

```
$div .= "<div id='SCid".$iscId."' class='schoolClass'>
                  <div class='schoolClassLeft'>
                    <div class='schoolCourseTitle'  onClick='classSessionEnter(SCid".$iscId.");' style='width:100%'>".$semesterName." ".$year." | ".$date1." &ndash; ".$date2."</div>
                  </div>
                </div>";
    echo($div);
```